# Bash :what is the syntax to create one spaces with sed

Tags: bash, shell

what is the syntax to create one spaces with sed

```
sed -e 's/Épisode \([0-9][^0-9]\)/Ep0\1/g' \
```

I want to create one space **Ep01 to Ep 01**

ty :)

Comment: Missing sample input & sample output ;)

Comment: You are trying to match something like "Episode 3a" (based on the regex you supply), and trying to replace it with "Ep03a". Assuming that is correct (which I don't think it is), you just need to specify the space manually in the replacement text: "Ep 0\1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed 's/[Ee]pisode\([0-9]+\)/Ep \1/g'
```

Substitutes 'Episode??' or 'episode ??' to 'Ep ??' In which ?? is a number greater than or equal to 0.

If you want 'Ep??' to 'Ep ??' use:

```
sed 's/\(Ep\)\([0-9]+\)/\1 \2/g'
```